# Datatime format is not working how the Oracle instructor said

Tags: sql, oracle

I just reviewed the OCA Certification question and I realized that something is incorrect. They ask:

> Please provide the time of hiring (HR user) from all users in
>   ascending order

So I wrote the next query:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date
  FROM employees 
 WHERE hire_date BETWEEN '01/01/80' AND '01/01/99'
 ORDER BY hire_date;
```

and the instructoe say that's incorrect, because that datatime is incorrect! that should be '01-JAN-80'. What? This is incredible!

I don't have a database installed on my laptop, but I am sure that I run this query several times at my last work and the data format is `/` and not `-`.

Any suggestion is welcome.

**UPDATE**

i just tested it in a xe 10g and is definitely `/` and not `-`:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/28/truethat.jpg/ ()

Comment: It depends on the NLS date format... either of you could be right. You didn't convert the string `'01/01/80'` explicitly to a date though.

Comment: They're right.  The default date format for Oracle is Day-MON-year. if you run your example you'll get not a valid month error.  You would have to cast your string to a date format with specific formatting to make it work like: `Select * from employees where hire_date between to_date('01/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('01/01/1999','MM/DD/YYYY')`  it's not the - / that messed you up its the JAN

Comment: i'm pretty sure that is not true., in few moments i'm gone tested it and prove it

Comment: I just did...NLS date format = DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS. but testing on your own... always a good thing.

Comment: i'm 100% sure that the 01/01/2012 datatime format is valid., right now i'm installing the xe database to tested it

Comment: as Ben pointed out in the base install of oracle the NLS date format is defied as DD-MON-RR.  if this remains unchanged, any queries you execute you must alter to the above.  I  ran both the above on a 11g oracle instance with NLS date format DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS.  Your's returned error .  The exact error message is: `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"`
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @hibigo, your update proves nothing. Without the NLS settings of the _session_ you were working in on the database that this question was asked on this question is _impossible_ to answer.

Comment: ok Ben, but why the instructor directly gives a negative for this issue!? edit later: is not wase nothing practical, only writing the answers.. so how to know in wich format is based the instrcutor

Comment: Maybe you were wrong? If the NLS date format on the database was the same as xQbert's then you certainly were. If it was `DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS`, for example, then you weren't, _it depends_ :-).

Comment: Tools-->Preferences-->database-->NLS parameters-->Date Format... what is it?  Mine reads DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS the instructor's is likely DD-MON-RR...  more importantly; what was it for the instructor?  and you avoid the whole debacle by doing a to_date so you explicitly define it.

Comment: the only thing i think is that the instructor need to say., ok i want the all possible formats for this query., and not play dirty with issue like this example

Comment: @xQbert, you mean `select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'` :-). Not everyone uses the same client to access the DB.

Comment: ahh and another big thing is the format, because the dateformat -JAN is not numbers format like 01/23/99

Comment: Yep see 2nd comment... and yes Ben; but I was basing it off his screenshot :D  but you're more right :D

Comment: my NLS format is: 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF' ., so i think that the instructor need to have the base of the places where are the courses, because clearly he not have a clue about the oracle country's configuration database

Comment: [form on topic](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=443190)

Comment: @xQbert this is my NLS http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/804/28986483.jpg/ .. btw i'm looking for a reasonable answer/opinion to explain to my instructor that his review is incorrect.

Comment: the format of dates are controlled by the session NLS format; which can be set at the user/session level.  If the question was stated such that in this environment how would you format a query to.... you'll lose.  If environment wasn't a factor then as Ben pointed out in comment 1.  The answer DEPENDS on the NLS format.  your answer and the teachers answer are both correct depending on the NLS format. That arguement could be made

Comment: lesson here is: always specify date format in your query, always.  Don't assume or depend on defaults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither you nor you instructor are correct.  Either of you might happen to be correct occasionally.

If you compare a date to a string, Oracle has to convert the string to a date.  In order to do that, it uses the session's current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  Different clients will have different default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`-- different regions use different default formats and different individuals will prefer different formats.  If you rely on implicit conversion, your code will fail whenever the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` doesn't match your expectations.  And, inevitably, that means that the code will fail at the most inopportune moment.

Instead of comparing a date to a string, you should **always** compare a date to a date.  There are two ways to do that in Oracle.  First, you can use an explicit `TO_DATE` with the appropriate format string, i.e.

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date
  FROM employees 
 WHERE hire_date BETWEEN to_date('01/01/80','mm/dd/rr') AND to_date('01/01/99','mm/dd/rr')
 ORDER BY hire_date;
```

Second, you can use ANSI date literals.  ANSI date literals always use the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date
  FROM employees 
 WHERE hire_date BETWEEN date '1980-01-01' AND date '1999-01-01'
 ORDER BY hire_date;
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I do not rely on implicit conversion. Too often this results in unexpected grief down the road. If asked to provide a filter between a date range, I would be explicit. Pick whatever format you want, but if it might be confusing, then try to eliminate as much of the confusion as possible:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date
  FROM employees 
  WHERE hire_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('JAN-01-1980', 'MON-DD-YYYY')
                      AND TO_DATE('JAN-01-1999', 'MON-DD-YYYY')
  ORDER BY hire_date;
```

Comment: +1 Always convert explicit in production code. Considering the long chain of overriding settings, you should never depend on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting outside of your own immediate control.